# Weird characters from Buffer when reading text file directly from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, express, buffer

Weird characters from Buffer when reading text file directly from Google Cloud Storage

I've been trying all kinds of encoding and sending out headers through express.js but I can't figure it out. My problem is that there are always a few characters that are squares with question marks. If I download the file it looks good. When I try to read the file directly it doesn't go well and shows square characters. I believe something is going wrong in the buffer. Do anyone have experience with reading files directly from Google Cloud Storage with text that are not English?

[image: showing the characters]

```
/* GET thing */
router.get('/thing/:filename', async function (req, res, next) {

    var filename = req.params.filename

    // works like a charm. i can open up the text file manually if I want and it looks good
    storage.bucket('mybucket')
        .file("folder/" + filename).download({
            destination: "./" + filename
        });

    // here is the trouble though, i can not get the stream to work
    console.log('Reading File');
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    var archivo = storage.bucket('mybucket')
        .file("folder/" + filename).createReadStream();

    console.log('Concat Data');
    var buf = '';
    archivo.on('data', function (d) {
        buf += d;
    }).on('end', function () {
        console.log("End");
        // print out the string
        // the string also prints out the weird characters in the console btw.
        res.json(buf);
    }).on('error', function (e) {
        res.json(e)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to be lucky enough to find the answer rather quickly after posting the question.

Not sure exactly what caused the problem but I ended up using string_decoder. I think there is a different version of UTF8 in the file (not sure) but that's why I had to decode it into utf8 (again) it seems.

```
var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;

var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');
```

So it would be like this.

```
  console.log('Concat Data');
  var buf = '';
  var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');
  archivo.on('data', function (d) {
    buf += decoder.write(d);
  }).on('end', function () {
    console.log("End");
    console.log(buf)
    res.json(buf);
    
  }).on('error', function (e) {
    res.json(e)
  });
```